# ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (229025,), (1,))

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working inside Jupyter notebook, and my understanding's that in the last line by calling
 `df_speed_full['cam_id'] == rand_cam_id` I label indices as `True` and `False`, and then pass them to outer `df_speed_full` to select only those with `True`. Yet somehow I'm getting this. I would appreciate an explanation of what am I missing here. I tried reading other answers but nothing clicks

```
rand_row = df_speed_full.sample(random_state=42)
rand_cam_id = list(rand_row['cam_id'])
rand_cam_df = df_speed_full[df_speed_full['cam_id'] == rand_cam_id]
```

And this is what I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\HENRYK~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18136/4206593172.py in <module>
----> 1 rand_cam_df = df_speed_full[df_speed_full['cam_id'] == rand_cam_id]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     68 
---> 69         return method(self, other)
     70 
     71     return new_method

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in __eq__(self, other)
     30     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__eq__")
     31     def __eq__(self, other):
---> 32         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
     33 
     34     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ne__")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   5500 
   5501         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 5502             res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
   5503 
   5504         return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    259         #  The ambiguous case is object-dtype.  See GH#27803
    260         if len(lvalues) != len(rvalues):
--> 261             raise ValueError(
    262                 "Lengths must match to compare", lvalues.shape, rvalues.shape
    263             )

ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (229025,), (1,))
```

Answer (score 1):

The complaint is on your `==` operation (visible by the fact that the special method `__eq__` is in the error traceback).

When comparing DataFrame or Series objects like `A == B` the following happens:

1. if `A` is a dataframe/series and `B` is a scalar, you get a dataframe/series of `True`/`False` saying if each element equals `B`
2. if `A` is a dataframe/series and `B` is a dataframe/series/list/numpy-array/something-like-that, then each element of `A` is compared with each corresponding element of `B`. This only works if `A` and `B` have the same *shape*.

You're getting into the 2nd option. But you're comparing a series with 229025 elements against a list that was expected to have 229025 elements but has only 1. This happens because you're matching against a `list` with a single element.

You probably want to replace the 2nd line with `rand_cam_id = list(rand_row['cam_id'])[0]`. This will make `rand_cam_id` not a list, but the single element that you're expecting to find in the list. That way, the `==` operation will go through the 1st option and give you the element-wise matches you expected.

Comment: I see it now, thanks a lot!